# Lazy Initialization causing deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

When i ran the following program it just hung forever and seems to me it is because of **deadlock**.

From my understanding I

- The static field `isInitialized` is initially set to `false`.
- Then the main thread creates a background thread whose run method
  sets `isInitialized`to `true`.
- The main thread starts the background thread and waits for it to
  complete by calling `join`.
- Once the background thread has completed, there can be no doubt that
  `isInitialized` must ha been set to True.

But when i ran the program, found that it prints nothing; it just hangs!

```
public class Test {
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;

    static {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                isInitialized = true;
            }
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isInitialized);
       }
    }
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior,Is there any deadlock if so why ?

Comment: I added some printlns; and to be precise: it is hanging in *run*; doing the assignment. It doesn't hang without the join call. Funny.